# Keycloak Admin UI 21.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am using Embedded keycloak v20.0.5.It was running fine until I upgraded it to 21.0.1.
Following this post (https://www.baeldung.com/keycloak-embedded-in-spring-boot-app).
When i click on User or group its giving me this error b.map is not a function.Their are no logs on server logs.
[image: Erros]

It should open users list like it was on 20.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a theme problem.

Try rebuilding the Java cache:

```
<PATH>/keycloak/bin/kc.sh --verbose build
```